# Create a task in outlook from excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, task

I have copy & pasted this code and modified it from a forum in Google to create a task in my Outlook based on what is on my form

```
With CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(3)
    .Subject = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value & " " & UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value
    .StartDate = UserForm1.MonthView1.Value
    .DueDate = UserForm1.MonthView1.Value
    .ReminderTime = UserForm1.MonthView1.Value - 1
    .Body = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value & " " & UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value
    .Save
End With
```

The code doesn't crash when I debug it, my program goes through it fine.   Is the method right?

Do I have to invoke CreateObject somewhere or can I just create the task from the With clause?

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but did you look in your Tasks view? It will not show up in your calendar.

Answer (score 1):

To start an Outlook automation session, you can use either early or late binding. Late binding uses either the `GetObject` or the `CreateObject` function to initialize Outlook. For example, the following code sets an object variable to the Outlook `Application` object, which is the highest-level object in the Outlook object model. All automation code must first define an Outlook Application object to be able to access any other Outlook objects.

```
Dim objOL as Object
Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

To use early binding, you first need to set a reference to the Outlook object library. You can then use the following syntax to start an Outlook session.

```
Dim objOL as Outlook.Application
Set objOL = New Outlook.Application
```

Most programming solutions interact with the data stored in Outlook. Outlook stores all of its information in Messaging Application Programming Interface (MAPI) folders. After you set an object variable to the Outlook Application object, you will commonly set a Namespace object to refer to MAPI, as shown in the following example.

```
Set objOL = New Outlook.Application
Set objNS = objOL.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
```

Once you have set an object variable to reference the folder that contains the items you wish to work with, you use appropriate code to accomplish your task, as shown in the following example.

```
Sub CreateNewDefaultOutlookTask()
  Dim objOLApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim NewTask As Outlook.TaskItem
  ' Set the Application object
  Set objOLApp = New Outlook.Application
  ' You can only use CreateItem for default items
  Set NewTask = objOLApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)
  ' Display the new task form so the user can fill it out
  NewTask.Display
  ' you can replace the .Display method with your own code for setting up the task item
End Sub
```

P.S. Don't forget to add an Outlook COM reference. On the Tools menu, click References. In the References box, click to select the Microsoft Outlook Object Library, and then click OK.

NOTE: If the Microsoft Outlook Object Library does not appear in the Available References box, browse your hard disk for the file, Msoutl*.olb. If you cannot locate this file, you must run the Microsoft Outlook Setup program to install it before you proceed further.